# I have implemented the shortcode plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, double-quotes

I have implemented the shortcode plugin from the link [quote](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quotes-shortcode-and-widget/)and i can use different quotes on different pages. But i want to implement the shortcode in page.php file to display the quote section in full width after the header.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[otw_shortcode_quote] [/otw_shortcode_quote]") ?>
```

Comment: use wordpress shortcode function in page.php where you want like : <?php echo do_shortcode('[put your shortcode here]');?>

Comment: but its not working <?php echo do_shortcode("[otw_shortcode_quote] [/otw_shortcode_quote]") ?>in header page what i do

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code 

<?php echo add_filter( 'the_content', do_shortcode("[otw_shortcode_quote]")); ?>
```

Comment: if i have update the above code in my page.php file.i am getting empty page with out any quote or content from editor. I have created about us, contact us, gallery like so many pages.i need to display each page with different quotes..